# Brother HL-L2360DW printer installation

Tags: printing, 14.10

I got exposed to Ubuntu Linux at the local public library and liked using it very much so I had it installed on my new Model `19-3013w HP` all-in-one PC.

Problem is, I am basically computer illiterate so am beginning to think that maybe I made a big mistake in doing so, but I hate Windows so I'm willing to give Ubuntu Linux a try.

I need help installing my brother Model `HL-L2360DW` printer using a USB cable.

I need some very easy to understand step-by-step instructions, can you help?

What is a good Ubuntu 14.10 Linux book for absolute beginners?

Answer (score 2):

Go to:

http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=hll2360dw_us&os=128

Download this files after agree to EULA.:

http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadend.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=hll2360dw_us&os=128&dlid=dlf101123_000&flang=4&type3=10032

http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadend.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=hll2360dw_us&os=128&dlid=dlf101125_000&flang=4&type3=10033

How to Install:

Turn on the printer and connect the usb, network or parallel cable.

Open a terminal. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>.

Run it:

```
   sudo -i
```

Go to the directory where the drivers are and install the drivers.

```
   cd /home/user/Downloads
   dpkg -i --force-all  brgenml1lpr-3.1.0-1.i386.deb
   dpkg -i --force-all  brgenml1cupswrapper-3.1.0-1.i386.deb
```

Check the configuration filename.

```
   cat /etc/printcap
```

For USB Connection (Default)

The parameter of ":lp" is:

```
:lp=/dev/usb/lp0
```

Open a web browser.

Go to:

```
http://localhost:631/printers.
```

Check if the Device URI of your printer is

```
usb://Brother/HL-L2360DW
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran the driver install tool from the Brother support site and it installed everything and worked perfectly over wifi:

1. Go to [support.brother.com](http://support.brother.com) > *Product Search* > HL-L2360DW > *Search* > *Downloads* > OS: *Linux* > Version: *Linux (deb)* > *Search* > *Driver Install Tool*
   (Here's the direct link I used: http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadend.aspx?c=ca&lang=en&prod=hll2360dw_us&os=128&dlid=dlf006893_000&flang=4&type3=625)
2. Click *Agree to the EULA and Download*
3. Follow the instructions on the page that loads. For me this was:

   1. Extract the install tool

      ```
      gunzip linux-brprinter-installer-2.1.1-1.gz
      ```
   2. Run the install tool

      ```
      sudo bash linux-brprinter-installer-2.1.1-1

      Input model name ->HL-L2360DW

      You are going to install following packages.
         hll2360dlpr-3.2.0-1.i386.deb
         hll2360dcupswrapper-3.2.0-1.i386.deb
      OK? [y/N] ->y

      Brother License Agreement
      Do you agree? [Y/n] ->y

      GPL License Agreement
      Do you agree? [Y/n] ->y

      Will you specify the Device URI? [Y/n] ->y

      ...
      14 (A): Auto. (dnssd://Brother%20HL-L2360D%20series._ipp._tcp.local/?uuid=28935df0-90c8-4892-b19e-95dfbaab1557)
      select the number of destination Device URI. ->a

      lpadmin -p HLL2360D -v dnssd://Brother%20HL-L2360D%20series._ipp._tcp.local/?uuid=28935df0-90c8-4892-b19e-95dfbaab1557 -E
      Test Print? [y/N] ->y

      wait 5s.
      lpr -P HLL2360D /usr/share/cups/data/testprint
      Hit Enter/Return key.
      ```

At the end of the installation it printed a test page and it worked perfectly!

Comment: On my Ubuntu 18.04 box, linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.2-2 runs, but with lots of errors (missing, mainly) so I'll give version 2.1.1-1 a try and stay away from the latest  version at the moment.